# how to use spark-corenlp in java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sparkcore

I am stuck while implementing spark-corenlp in java. I am unable to figure out steps for below scala code in java. [spark-corenlp git](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp)

**scala example:**

```
val input = Seq(
  (1, "<xml>Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university.</xml>")
).toDF("id", "text")
val output = input
  .select(cleanxml('text).as('doc))
  .select(explode(ssplit('doc)).as('sen))
  .select('sen, tokenize('sen).as('words), ner('sen).as('nerTags), sentiment('sen).as('sentiment))
```

**Java :**

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> rdd= new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).parallelizePairs(
                Arrays.asList(new Tuple2[]{
                        new Tuple2<Integer,String>(1,"<xml>Stanford University is located in California. " +
                                "It is a great university.</xml>")}));
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.rdd(),Type.class);
     // steps to implement nlp ?
```

Thanks for your help.